# Can't click a href tag link

Tags: html, css, href

i have an html structure which act like sidebar menu:

```
<div class="sidebar sidebar-main">
   <div class="wk-seller">
      <div class="section">
         <a class="store-name" href="https://booyaa.id/marketplace/seller/feedback/shop/adityathevendor">
         Penilaian                      </a>
      </div>
      <div class="section">
         <a class="store-name" href="https://booyaa.id/marketplace/seller/profile/shop/adityathevendor#return-policy">
         Return Policy                          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="section">
         <a class="store-name" href="https://booyaa.id/marketplace/seller/profile/shop/adityathevendor#shipping-policy">
         Kebijakan Pengiriman                           </a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

the problem is i add the pseudoelement style to the sidebar-main like this:

```
.sidebar.sidebar-main:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 22px;
    border: solid 1px #dae2e6;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

it makes the a href tag inside this html structure not clickable, how can i fix this?

Comment: It is working ..

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: The link is "clickable" - in edge. However agree with @Quentin.

Comment: When you give this rule a background color `.sidebar.sidebar-main::before` you can see that it is in front of the links. so you cant click them.

Comment: `.sidebar.sidebar-main::before` covers the area. If you really need that pseudo element, make sure you add `pointer-events: none;` to its CSS to make it click-through.

Comment: No MCVE, no code in the question, two people unable to reproduce the problem, and three upvotes?!

Comment: Blimey, glory rep hunters coming in :D I think we have a "down-vote" war going on.

Comment: **add this** style in our css `.wk-mp-design {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 12;
} .sidebar.sidebar-main::before {
    z-index: 9;

}` it's working fine

Comment: @Quentin Evenmoreso, 4 downvotes on the correct answer...

Comment: @connexo unfortunately, I think you was struck by rep-hunters jealousy. In all fairness this sort of "down-vote" war on SO should not be tolerated. I treat SO as a professional platform, to find and answer budding developers problems - as well as seeking answers to my own problems. It's become heavily focused on competition and points rather than a community - on that note, I'll upvote you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a pseudo element `.sidebar.sidebar-main::before` covering the area. If you really need that pseudo element, make sure you add `pointer-events: none;` to its CSS to make it click-through.

[image]

Comment: thanks for learning a new element